# Wordpress not updating Updating Plugin Paid Memberships Pro - Sponsored Members Add On

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress site for a non-profit.  They are using the "free" PaidMembershipsPro plugin.  They have used it for a few years without issue.  However, the most recent update for the plugin `Updating Plugin Paid Memberships Pro - Sponsored Members Add On` will not apply.  the error is:

```
You must have a valid PMPro Plus License Key to update PMPro Plus add ons. The following plugins will not be updated: Paid Memberships Pro - Sponsored Members Add On

The update process is starting. This process may take a while on some hosts, so please be patient.

Updating Plugin Paid Memberships Pro - Sponsored Members Add On (1/1)
Downloading update from http://license.paidmembershipspro.com/downloads/plus/pmpro-sponsored-members.zip…

Unpacking the update…

An error occurred while updating Paid Memberships Pro - Sponsored Members Add On: The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature
```

Have they made this a non-free plugin?  Since the non-profit is using the free version there is no access to the support forums and little useful info that i can find on the site.

Comment: Visiting that link looks like you need a License key? But it does seem to be a free plugin still. Maybe that update from link is wrong? You can try contact their support page

Comment: Thanks.  After more investigation it turns out the web site is not using that plugin so I just removed it.